# SOQL Count() Vs Query data which is more faster?

Tags: soql, performance

If you want to check if there is record of ProcessInstance exists in the system or not, please suggest which one of the following approch is faster and best practice to use ?

Approch 1 - Query Object with Id field and check list has returned any rows or not.

```
Select TargetObjectId, Status From ProcessInstance where TargetObjectId='006g0000003AitI' and Status='Pending' limit 1
```

Approch 2 -  Use Count SOQL to check if any records exists in the system or not as follows -

```
Select count() From ProcessInstance where TargetObjectId='006g0000003AitI' and Status='Pending'
```

I tested it in terms of timing there is no significant difference between both.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need count then you should use `count()`. There is no timing difference and effects on governor limit but It has difference in `heap-size`.

In your first approach `heap` will significantly more than your second approach as you are querying data and then counting. In Second, `SOQL` returns a `Integer` only (no data).

First approach is useful if you want to populate data or want to make some  use in you code. Only for counting, why should query **data** and then count is programmatically ( adding more character in code), if `SOQL` has given a feature to count on his behalf.

---

Update (04-Feb-2016)
**Stats on running query over `2,264,510` records:**

1. Simple Query
   [image]
2. Count Query
   [image]
3. Aggregate Query (Added filter to prevent 50000 limit)
   [image]

Comment: Sorry, there won't be a 'significant' difference in heap, maybe just a few bytes, in practice. Might even be zero difference in heap, depending on the precise code structure. Of course, if they optimized the query a bit, the field select query might even be arguably faster than the count query, but in the end, it just doesn't matter.

Comment: What in the case: `[SELECT id, name... and hundred more fields.. FROM Account]` and `[SELECT count() FROM Account]`. Here one is bad practice and other is good. `[SELECT count()...]` remove that possibility. Also `heap` single byte matters in big project otherwise governor limit won't be as small to 6MB. And also By `count()` we can count  rows by single line of code using count(), what is good with `[SELECT id FROM Account]` then calculate list size? @sfdcfox

Comment: There's an axiom about database queries: do not query more than you need. In that sense, the question's original query should have selected only an ID value. Querying 100 fields to determine the number of rows is clearly not optimal, but doesn't fall under the premise of this question. As it is written, this falls under the axioms "do not optimize any code before its time" and "premature optimization is the root of all evil." This answer has a decent premise, but its just not right. `SELECT Count()` vs `SELECT Id` is the focus, and there is no difference.

Comment: Also, we're not querying Accounts, we're querying a specific type of object that can't use much heap, won't have many results, and is indexed. If you want to get down to it, you're not even looking for a number, but a Boolean value: `[SELECT COUNT() ...] == 1` vs `![SELECT Id ...].isEmpty()`. Virtually no difference in code size, performance, timing, etc (I count one byte more in total code).

Comment: `[SELECT id...]` and `[SELECT count()]` don't have much difference practically (but has difference). But if requirement don't need count then Why should use `[SELECT id..]`. In future if requirement need data then in both case code need refactoring, `[SELECT id FROM Account]` won't be helpful. Possibly require few more fields. I have written in answer "if there need to count only then why data?" Is there some other reason for `count()` except need # of rows then? I think `[SELECT count()..]` return `Integer`. @sfdcfox

Comment: There is a difference in performance for large queries, etc, but *not in this case*. It simply doesn't matter, but using `SELECT count()` requires MORE refactoring than using `SELECT Id` if you later need data. On the other hand, let's say you need this data in a trigger. Using `SELECT Id ... LIMIT` would get you in trouble, you'd want to use `count()` and `group by`.

Comment: There can be several scenarios can be assumed where `count()` is more helpful over `[SELECT id..]` or `[SELECT id..]` is helpful over `count()`, that is the matter of use cases. In simple scenario, we are confirmed that we need count of records; lets say we want to show * you have 10 dashboard saved* then why we need `[SELECT id..]`. `count()` will be enough. OP Question requires only to check if record exist or not? then to do this `count()` is enough. There is no use of `id` os something if query. It is rule *do not query more than you need*, here we don't need any field. @sfdcfox

Comment: You're allowed to have this opinion of using `count()` over `id` in this specific case, and it's perfectly valid. However, I believe we've strayed from my original intent, which is to state that **it does not matter** which method the questioner uses, because it is a premature optimization that never needs to be made. Trying to apply an optimization is much like [The Fox and the Cat](http://www.taleswithmorals.com/aesop-fable-the-fox-and-the-cat.htm), where the fox had so many tricks he got caught, while the cat, with just one trick, escaped.

Comment: did anyone do some benchmarking on this? i get the concern about pre-mature optimization, but would be curious to see some actual numbers on a large database table. It doesn't seem unreasonable that the underlying implementation of `COUNT()` vs `COUNT(Id)` vs `SELECT Id` would be noticeable, I've seen stranger issues with salesforce before, either way some data could settle it.

Comment: @RalphCallaway Added some stats. Hope it help you :)

Answer (score 2):

The question is philosophical in nature, since the minute differences in terms of space and time costs are statistically insignificant. You should pick one mode of operation and then optimize any other code that's actually going to impact your application's performance.

The query time spent will be the virtually the same, and very close to zero (I'd guess less than 2ms with either query, and far less than 1ms difference, on average, between the two). The latency in the database would normalize any possibility of coming up with meaningful results.

Depending on the use case for this code, it's possible that the difference in heap space may also be zero, since heap space is only checked every few lines of code.

Personally, I would accept the possible few extra bytes of heap size from the first query, in case I later needed to modify the code to use some of the data that `count()` can't return.

Instead of worrying about a few bytes of heap and nanosecond timings, you should instead focus your concerns on things that do make an impact, such as exponential `for-for` loops, queries inside `for` loops, and so on.

> Premature optimization is the root of all evil. -- Donald Knuth